# Adding Contacts to Address Book(IPhone) from VCard

Tags: iphone, addressbook, vcf-vcard

I need to add a contact in AddressBook of IPhone from the VCard i am getting from the server. Is there a way to do it in IPhone or i need to parse the Vcard file and create the IPhone contact from it.
and i also need to send the contact in form of Vcard to the server. Is there a Framework or Api that do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address book api is a PITA... This should help you:

http://mrrask.wordpress.com/2009/01/18/add-entry-to-contacts-using-iphone-sdk/

For the official Apple doc, I am sure you are aware that Google can help, just search "iphone os address book api".

EDIT: Oops, I forgot to mention that you will have to parse the vcard file by yourself, no API for that in the iPhone OS. Check out the [ccard project at Sourceforge](http://ccard.sourceforge.net/).

-- Arnaud